# ActiveDataProvider not returning actual data if merged with other params for REST api - Yii2

Tags: rest, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dataprovider

I made an application which is providing data to my mobile devices via rest api. 
I am having data coming from various tables based on the relations established between them via keys(Foreign/Index).

I am using `ActiveDataProvider` to extract required data from tables.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
   'query'=>$query
]);
```

This is working great based on the query I set and returning data in `JSON` format as I needed when I return it as follows:

```
return $dataProvider;
```

What I want is:

- Return data of this ActiveDataProvider along with some other data. Like all data from ActiveDataProvider in one object and other data say some flag values in another object.

For example:

```
[
  "some_other_data":{
     -----
  },
  "dataProvider": {
    "device_id": "552255445511",
    "dated": "2016-03-15 23:00:04",
    "speed": "73.30",
    "power": null,
    "ignition": null,
    "ac": null,
    "address": "52",
    "latitude": "30.4575",
    "longitude": "76.1",
    "devices": {
      "vehicle_number": "UK 6S Z 5555",
      "vehicle_type": "0"
    }
  }
]
```

The issue is when I return it as:

```
return array('some_other_data'=>$somedata, 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider);
```

then the result is like:

```
{
  "some_other_data": 0,
  "dataProvider": {
    "query": {
      "sql": null,
      "on": null,
      "joinWith": null,
      "select": null,
      "selectOption": null,
      "distinct": null,
      "from": null,
      "groupBy": null,
      "join": null,
      "having": null,
      "union": null,
      "params": [],
      "where": {
        "tk103_current_location.device_id": {
          "sql": null,
          "on": null,
          "joinWith": null,
          "select": [
            "device_id"
          ],
          "selectOption": null,
          "distinct": null,
          "from": null,
          "groupBy": null,
          "join": null,
          "having": null,
          "union": null,
          "params": [],
          "where": {
            "transporter_id": 22
          },
          "limit": null,
          "offset": null,
          "orderBy": null,
          "indexBy": null,
          "modelClass": "api\\modules\\v1\\models\\Tk103Devices",
          "with": null,
          "asArray": null,
          "multiple": null,
          "primaryModel": null,
          "link": null,
          "via": null,
          "inverseOf": null
        }
      },
      "limit": null,
      "offset": null,
      "orderBy": null,
      "indexBy": null,
      "modelClass": "api\\modules\\v1\\models\\Tk103CurrentLocation",
      "with": null,
      "asArray": null,
      "multiple": null,
      "primaryModel": null,
      "link": null,
      "via": null,
      "inverseOf": null
    },
    "key": null,
    "db": null,
    "id": null
  }
}
```

i.e. ActiveDataProvider is returning the schema like data in the result, not the actual result.

Please give me a clue or hint how to force this dataProvider to return actual data, not the architecture by which it is trying to return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
return array('some_other_data'=>$somedata, 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider->getModels());
```

Comment: Awesome.. But I think I lost my mind. I did see documentation a number of times but not looked over getModels(). Thanks dude. It was such a small thing & I was not getting that. +1

Comment: yii\rest\Serializer line#172, yii2 did the same thing at rest controller. :)